# Conditional based on result_array()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, and i want to make a conditional based on return value from model.

here is the model:

```
    public function get_sentitems()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('sentitems');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and here is the controller:

```
    public function sentitems()
{
    $data['sentitems'] = $this->sms_model->get_sentitems();

    if($data['sentitems']['Status'] === 'SendingOKNoReport')
    {
        $data['status_message'] = 'Sent';
    }
    else
    {
        $data['status_message'] = 'Failed';
    }

    $data['title'] = ucwords('sent items');

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('sms/sentitems', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

And here is the view

```
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Tujuan</th>
            <th>Waktu</th>
            <th>Isi</th>
            <th>Ket.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($sentitems as $sentitems_item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $sentitems_item['ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sentitems_item['DestinationNumber']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sentitems_item['SendingDateTime']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sentitems_item['TextDecoded']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sentitems_item['Status']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a column **Status**, but why the result in browser is always like this:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: Status
>   Filename: controllers/sms.php
>   Line Number: 62

What is the solution? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you had a look at what `$data['sentitems']` actually contains?

Comment: it contains many index, such as `$data['sentitems']['ID']`,`$data['sentitems']['DestinationNumber']`,`$data['sentitems']['SendingDateTime']`,`$data['sentitems']['TextDecoded']` and also `$data['sentitems']['Status']`. And it can displayed in the View. But not display in the controller

Comment: `$data['sentitems']['Status']` doesn't exist, or you wouldn't be getting the error. Maybe you should try `if(isset($data['sentitems']['Status']) && $data['sentitems']['Status'] === 'SendingOKNoReport')`

Comment: you can see the result: http://www.tanyapedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Untitled1.jpg the variable Status is can display in the view, but it can't display in controller.

Comment: i just want to change the text `SendingOKNoReport` with my own text. Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in your controller `$data['sentitems']` contains an array of results from your database, so you cannot get at it with `$data['sentitems']['Status']`. What you actually have is

```
$data['sentitems'][0]['Status']
$data['sentitems'][1]['Status']
$data['sentitems'][2]['Status']
```

and so on.

I think your best option at this point is to remove the following from your controller:

```
if($data['sentitems']['Status'] === 'SendingOKNoReport')
{
    $data['status_message'] = 'Sent';
}
else
{
    $data['status_message'] = 'Failed';
}
```

and amend the line of your template that outputs the status to:

```
<td><?php echo $sentitems_item['Status'] == 'SendingOKNoReport' ? 'Sent' : 'Failed'; ?></td>
```

Comment: thanks. and why if i want to use 3 condition in `$sentitems['Status']`, example: `'SendingOK'`, `'SendingOKNoreport'` and `'SendingError'` ?

Comment: If it's getting more complicated you could consider writing a helper to translate the value you're getting to the one you want. You can instantiate a helper in your controller and pass it into the view.